# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array on laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**I'm using Laravel 5.0.**
I'm getting one register on my table, with all conditions.

**My function of model:**

```
public static function getParcelas($id){
    return DB::table('academia_matricula_parcelas')
    ->select('academia_matricula_parcelas.data_validade')
    ->where('academia_matricula_id', '=', $id)
    ->where('data_validade', '<>', "0000-00-00")
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->first();
}
```

**Getting the result:**

```
$parcelas = App\academia_matricula_parcelas::getParcelas($item->id);
```

My `var_dump($parcelas)`:

```
{#504 ▼
    +"data_validade": "1970-03-01"
}
```

When I try to show `$parcelas->data_validade` in my view, occurs the follow error:

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: show me how you can pass this $parcelas on your view?

Comment: For which line you are getting the error?

Comment: You can do toArray() to convert it to Array if you want it.

DB::table('academia_matricula_parcelas')
        ->select('academia_matricula_parcelas.data_validade')
        ->where('academia_matricula_id', '=', $id)
        ->where('data_validade', '<>', "0000-00-00")
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->first()
        ->toArray();

Comment: try putting this line \DB::setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: toArray don't work, result this on error: Call to undefined method stdClass::toArray()

Comment: \DB::setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) WORK! Thanks Jaimin

Comment: @TeddyWinters cheers mate!

Comment: \DB::setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) converts with success my return for array, but when i try show with echo $parcelas->data_validade, Results in error.

Comment: Follow error: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @Jaimin, help, same error above: Trying to get property of non-object.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this,

```
public static function getParcelas($id){
    \DB::setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return \DB::table('academia_matricula_parcelas')
    ->select('academia_matricula_parcelas.data_validade')
    ->where('academia_matricula_id', '=', $id)
    ->where('data_validade', '<>', "0000-00-00")
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->first();
}
```

and try to debug this $parcelas['data_validade'];

Comment: \DB::setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) converts with success my return for array, but when i try show with echo $parcelas->data_validade, Results in error.

Comment: echo $parcelas['data_validade'];

Comment: Follow error: Trying to get property of non-object. My var_dump:                   `array:1 [▼
  "data_validade" => "1970-03-01"
]`

Comment: try $parcelas[0]['data_validade']

Comment: result: Undefined offset: 0

Comment: dd($parcelas); what is the response?

Comment: var_dump with ´$parcelas['data_validade'];´, but echo don't works

Comment: write dd($parcelas); and tell me what is the response

Comment: Responds well: array:1 [▼
  "data_validade" => "1970-03-01"
]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write $parcelas['data_validade']. does this help!